# Preventing entire table from locking while bulk INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that performs a bulk insert in a table. I added `BEGIN TRANSACTION` command just above the `INSERT` query to enable `ROLL BACK` if something goes wrong. When the bulk insert initiated, it locked the entire table and other users were unable to execute `SELECT` on the same table.

I am not following why SQL Server locks entire table for even a `SELECT`.

I am using SQL Server 2005 Express. Is this a problem with this version or it persists in 2008 as well? How to overcome this situation? **Writers should not block Readers**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You have an open transaction.**  That means SQL Server needs to preserve the state of the table, and any changes you are in the process of making are "dirty" and uncommitted.

If you `SELECT` from a table that is currently being altered with an open (explicit) transaction, the `SELECT` will wait until the table is in a stable state and the transaction has been either committed or rolled back.

To get around this, [you can alter the transaction isolation level on the `SELECT` query.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

*Writers should not block Readers*

This is true only for [snapshot isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), all other isolation levels require both readers to block writes and writers to block readers (dirty reads not considered, since they are [inconsistent](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2007/02/01/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used.aspx) and should never be used). If you need this behavior, then use row versioning (the link contains the solution).

*Why does bulk insert lock the entire table?*

This actually may or may not be true. The behavior is under your control:

> **TABLOCK**
>
> Specifies that a table-level lock is acquired for the duration of
>   the bulk-import operation. A table can be loaded concurrently by
>   multiple clients if the table has no indexes and TABLOCK is specified.
>   By default, locking behavior is determined by the table option `table
>   lock on bulk load`.

For more details, read the product specifications: [Controlling Locking Behavior for Bulk Import](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180876.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

If you're specifying [TABLOCK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) in your proc, don't.